# Fetching data inside of mapped function, or alternate method?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to fetch from something, but i need previously fetched data to determine the URL.
But cannot do await/async inside of a map function.

Not sure how else to go about getting this data.

I've added `//comments` where the problem is
I *know* why the problem occurs, just not a way around it.

```
const fetchData = async (playerName: string): Promise<Result> => {
  const req = await fetch("data-site.com" + player);
  const data: string = await req.text();
  const $ = cheerio.load(data);

  const dataElements: Element[] = $("#network > div > div.content > div.display > div.tournament" 
          ).toArray();

  const tournaments: Tournament[] = tournamentElements.map((el: Element) => {
      const league: string = $(el)
        .find(".league")
        .text()

      const moreData = await fetch('www.example-data' + league + '.json'); // problem here

         const playerStats: PlayerStats[] = $(el)
        .find(".player")
        .toArray()
        .map((el: Element) => {
          const name: string = ($(el).attr("title") || "");
          const stats = moreData[name].stats; // problem here

          return { name, stats};
        });

      return {
        league,
        playerStats,
      };
    })
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **promise.all** if you want to use async-await inside map or for each.

```js
const playerStats: PlayerStats[] = Promise.all($(el)
        .find(".player")
        .toArray()
        .map(aysnc(el: Element) => {
          const name: string = ($(el).attr("title") || "");
          const stats = await moreData[name].stats; // problem here

          return { name, stats};
        }));
```